# ViewPager scrolling issue in Android

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I have a `ViewPager` with dynamic number of `images` in it. This `ViewPager` is added as a custom row to a table view. As this table view can have multiple dynamic custom rows, I have to add this table view in a `scrollview` for scrolling.

Now my question is, when I am scrolling horizontally to View Pager, it's not exactly horizontal scrolling, it's mixed with some vertical scrolling as well. So when a vertical scrolling is detected the events are passed to the scroll view; which makes the `ViewPager` reset to the initial position.

So how can I pass back the events to `ViewPager` or avoid scrollview catching vertical scroll events?

**Note:** I tried disabling `scrollview` to vertical scrolling but that didn't stop it from capturing the vertical scroll events.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution for my question and this is how I did it.

I over ride the on touch event for my Viewpager in the following way

```
myViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && myScrollView!=null){
                        myScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Note: myScrollView is parent of myViewPager, as said in my question.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. We should not need such tricks I think. What kind of bug is this